# Beamer: overlayarea inside a figure?

Tags: beamer, overlays

In my `beamer` presentation, I would like to dynamically switch images in a `figure` environment. More precisely, my figure contains 9 subfloats presented 3x3 and each of them should switch between two images during the presentation.

In order to avoid some "tilting" between the different elements, I thought that it would be a good idea to use an `overlayarea` inside each subfloat.

Sadly, when used in an `figure` environment, the overlayarea seems to behave very odd: every thing I put in it appear *outside* the `overlayarea`?

Here is a very short example :

```
\documentclass[9pt, aspectratio=43]{beamer}

\usepackage [francais]{babel}
\usepackage [T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage [utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[position=top]{subfig}
\usepackage{pdfpages}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
%% This works fine : 123 appears INSIDE the overlayarea
\fbox{\begin{overlayarea}{3cm}{2cm}
\fbox{123}
\end{overlayarea}}

%% This looks odd : 456 appears OUTSIDE the overlayarea
\begin{figure}
\fbox{\begin{overlayarea}{3cm}{2cm}
\fbox{456}
\end{overlayarea}}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Perhaps I misuse this environment?

Comment: Welcome ! Please provide us a MWE :: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your answer :)
A MWE is already provided in my initial message :

`%% This looks odd : 456 appears OUTSIDE the overlayarea
\begin{figure}
\fbox{\begin{overlayarea}{3cm}{2cm}
\fbox{456}
\end{overlayarea}}
\end{figure}`

Comment: Please read the link : your example is not a MWE.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what happens with OPs code but an alternative construction for what I understand Donut's wants could be a `tabular` with equal fixed size for every image pair.

```
\documentclass[9pt, aspectratio=43]{beamer}

\usepackage [francais]{babel}
\usepackage [T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage [utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[position=top]{subfig}
\usepackage{pdfpages}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
%% This works fine : 123 appears INSIDE the overlayarea
%\fbox{\begin{overlayarea}{3cm}{2cm}
%\fbox{123}
%\end{overlayarea}}

%% This looks odd : 456 appears OUTSIDE the overlayarea
\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\only<1>{\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{example-image-a}}%
\only<2>{\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{example-image-b}}
&
\only<1>{\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{example-image-a}}%
\only<2>{\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{example-image-b}}
&
\only<1>{\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{example-image-a}}%
\only<2>{\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{example-image-b}}
\\
\only<1>{\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{example-image-a}}%
\only<2>{\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{example-image-b}}
&
\only<1>{\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{example-image-a}}%
\only<2>{\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{example-image-b}}
&
\only<1>{\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{example-image-a}}%
\only<2>{\includegraphics[width=3cm, height=2cm]{example-image-b}}
\end{tabular}%
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]